# Accessing getter methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hi guys please can anyone help out this error: ***"Accessing unknown' lives' getter method"*** I am getting  on the 2nd line(CCSprite line) of the code below.

GamePlayLayer.h is:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "GLES-Render.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@class UILayer;
@class Insect;

@interface GamePlayLayer : CCLayer {

b2World * world;
GLESDebugDraw * debugDraw;
CCSpriteBatchNode * sceneSpriteBatchNode;
Insect * insect;
b2Body *body;
SceneUILayer * uiLayer;
    double startTime;
bool gameOver;
bool gameWon;
NSMutableArray *lives;

}

- (id)initWithUILayer:(UILayer *)sceneUILayer;


@end
```

GamePlayLayer.m

```
UILayer * sr = (UILayer *)[self.parent getChildByTag:10];
CCSprite * live = [sr.lives objectAtIndex:self.lives];
[live setVisible:NO];
```

Allright I have to add the following information:

The UILayer.h (The UILayer is the HUD layer)file is :

```
@interface UILayer : CCLayer {

NSMutableArray *lives;

   }

 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *lives;
```

The UILayer.m is:

```
#import "UILayer.h"
#import "GameManager.h"


@implementation UILayer


@synthesize lives;

    - (id)init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {


    lives = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3]retain];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        CCSprite * life = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life_Label.png"];
        [life setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/18+ 32*i,290)];
        [self addChild:life];
        [lives addObject:life];
    }
   }
```

Comment: You should include your header for whatever type 'self' is here, where you declare this lives property. And what is a UILayer?

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer I have added more codes, hope its clearer

Comment: @FirozeLafeer The first code snippet I posted was from GamePlayLayer(look up).

Comment: I'm asking for the the header. GamePlayLayer.h

Comment: @FirozeLafeer Ok I have included it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then now we can see that GamePlayLayer does not have a property called 'lives'. So that is why 'self.lives' is an error.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer So what you are saying is that despite initialising both the uilayer and the gameplay layer within the scene I still need to declare the lives property...? Anyway, thanks I will try it out.

Comment: Well, next the problem you'll have is trying to use an array as an index into another array. You may just want to go back and read all the answers very carefully again.

Answer (score 0):

The way that the compiler sees your method -setVisible is a setter method for a property visible. I'm guessing that isn't what you intended. Try renaming your method to something like [live visible:NO]; or anything other than -set.

Comment: You will also see similar issues for methods that begin with -add -copy or -new.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @BillBrasky If I set it to visible then I get a warning that CCSprite may not respond to -visible.

Comment: You may need to adjust where that method is at, or add the method to your header so your .m file can see it. If it is above where it is being used, that should work. If the method is below where it is being called, it won't. Hopefully that is all you need to do. But I would probably add it to my header to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

are you defining a property for lives?

e.g. in your .h:

```
@interface blah

// ...

@property (assign) NSInteger lives;

@end
```

then in your .m:

```
@implementation blah

@synthesize lives = _lives;

//your code

@end
```

Comment: Yes I am adding a property for the lives. Sorry I did not mention but my lives ivar is defined as a NSMutableArray and not NSInteger i.e NSMutableArray *lives;

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- have no `@property int lives;` in header file
- have no `@synthesize lives;` in implementation file.
- have `lives` as something else than `int` (or convertible to `int`).

But it's just a poor guessing with the snippet you have provided.

Comment: I have my lives ivar as an NSMutableArray and not as an int.

Comment: Fix up the line `[sr.lives objectAtIndex:self.lives];` - you are passing an array twice? `objectAtIndex:` takes an integer index.

Comment: I have some images that I want to be removed one after the other hence the array and the object at index. So what do I do here?

Comment: Pass the valid index. Item at which index do you want to get removed?

Comment: I have added more codes for a better picture of what is happening.

Comment: You need to answer the simple question first: which life do you want to hide? When you already have this answer, put it as a parameter of `objectAtIndex:` instead of `self.lives`.

Comment: there are three lives indexed(0,1 and 2,). I want to remove one  life after the other until I get no life left. So what do I do?

Comment: For the first time, do: `[sr.lives objectAtIndex: 0]`, next time `[sr.lives objectAtIndex: 1]`, etc. I'm sure you can figure it out now.